# Understanding classes in Lua

Tags: lua

I have been playing around in Lua looking to find out why and how I get a "Attempt to call field 'copy'(nil value)" when defining a "class" in Lua.

```
local factionClass = {}
factionClass.Name = "throwaway"

function factionClass:New(name)
    local newFaction = table.Copy(factionClass)
    if name then
        newFaction.Name = name
    end
    return newFaction
end

factionCoolguys = Faction("cool guys")
```

Comment: `copy` or `Copy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Lua has no concept of objects or classes; they are usually implemented as tables containing functions.
2. The reason for that error is exactly as it says: you are attempting to call nil.
   The function you're trying to call, `table.copy`, [does not exist](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.6), so Lua complains when you attempt to call it. This is because:
3. If something is undefined, it is `nil`, which is a valid "value", unlike in languages like C, where an undefined variable just doesn't exist. `nil` cannot be called though, which causes your error.
4. In almost all cases, "Attempt to call field X (nil value)" should be read as "Attempt to call a function that does not exist (X)", which would be a more comprehensible error message.
5. Instead of copying the contents of the class into the new instance, it's common in Lua to use [metatables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) to look up keys that don't exist in the object within its class. See [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) for more information on this.